# "Assertion failed" error when running coroutines in edit mode - Unity

Tags: unity, coroutines, text-mesh-pro

TLDR:
Calling coroutines from OnValidate in edit mode leads to following error:

```
Assertion failed on expression: 'ShouldRunBehaviour()'
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine (string)
script:OnValidate () (at Assets/script.cs:12)
```

Code (simplified to recreate error from main project):

```
public class script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int number;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        StartCoroutine("coroutine");
    }

    IEnumerator coroutine()
    {
        print(number);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Long version:

Making a background generator for TextMeshPro using "Shapes" plugin. Must work in both edit mode and play mode. For reasons, `TextMeshPro.textBounds` is not updated until the frame after the one you set the actual text. So setting the background in that frame gives you the dimensions for the previous frame's text.

I don't want to set the new dimensions every frame, but a coroutine with `WaitForEndOfFrame` fixed the issue. However I get the assertion error in the editor.

Thanks for any help.